# Restrict Content for only Contributors via .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, security

I have been using this code to restrict content download from wp-content/uploads for only logged in users:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 # Add these lines right after the preceding two
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf|docx)$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

However, this will allow all logged in users to download the same. Is there any way that ONLY Contributors / Authors are able to download the files and not subscribers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't do that using .htaccess.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: The only way I'm aware is to block *all* calls with `.htaccess` and instead provide a download url which takes them through your application and decides whether or not to serve the file. Will post a proper answer later.

Comment: Also, you realize that the above only checks for a cookie existing, and not it actually being valid, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom page template for downloads and use something similar to the following:

```
if (current_user_can('contributor')) { 
    echo "<h2>Download Page</h2>"; 
} else { 
    echo 'You do not have access to this page";
}
```

You would need additional code to show the file you are offering for download.

Alternatively you could set another cookie and check value of that.